# Problemas con tiggers Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, api, trigger, insert

Estoy creado un trigger que inserte una nueva `idAlumno` con el parámetro de `matrícula` del registro. Y que el parámetro de `idMatricula` se actualice con el parámetro `matrícula`.

Tengo la sintaxis de un trigger que estaba elaborando pero este no funciona.

Me gustaría saber en que estoy mal y como puedo corregirlo.

Aquí esta mi código:

**Corregido**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `registrobiblioteca`.`alumno_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `alumno` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

update registro set idMatricula = new.idAlumno;

END
```

---

**Con errores**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `registrobiblioteca`.`alumno_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `alumno` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

update registro set idMatricula = new.idAlumno;

END
```

"ERROR 1442"

La estructura de las tablas es la siguiente:

```
Table: alumno
Columns:
idAlumno int(11) AI PK 
nombre varchar(100) 
Grado int(2) 
Grupo varchar(45) 
idProgramaE int(11)


Table: registro
Columns:
idRegistro int(6) AI PK 
entrada datetime 
Matricula int(6) 
idMatricula int(11)
```

Comment: Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `registrobiblioteca`.`registro` (`Matricula`) VALUES ('180600');

ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'registro' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `registrobiblioteca`.`registro` (`Matricula`) VALUES ('180600')

Comment: El código que colocas como corregido es igual al que tienes "con errores". ¿Puedes revisar por favor?

Comment: El error que dices que te da sugiere un escenario distinto del que se ve en el trigger de la pregunta. Se refiere a una sentencia `insert into registrobiblioteca.registro`, y el trigger es sobre la tabla `alumno` y hace un `update` en la tabla `registro`.  Sugiero que incluyas la sentencia original y todos los triggers involucrados, pues el error indica que de la sentencia que lanzas a la base de datos, directa o indirectamente modifica primero la tabla `registro` y luego se intenta hacer un `insert` nuevamente en la misma tabla.